# Assign different IP for different threads in a .net program

Tags: c#, .net, networking, network-programming

The computer that runs my program has 6 different IP addresses assigned to it. I need that each thread will use a different IP address for its communication.

Specifically I'm using the WebRequest object for communicating. so is there away assign each thread a different IP address to use instead of the default one?

Thanks,
Eden

Answer (score 0):

There is some info [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/a7a540cf-55a9-4d8d-9cb0-8dfdc5b1f704) about binding before making the call. I suspect you'll need to work lower than WebRequest at the socket layer itself.

Comment: I suspect you are right (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/7dd20c91-2c22-4f1f-b6d6-d2be07663c47/)

Is there away to access the WebRequest underlying socket?